# Ansible: How to pass multiple password files to playbook

Tags: ansible

When I run an Ansible playbook, how do I pass multiple password files on the command line?

I want to run this:

```
ansible-playbook --vault-password-file /path/to/vault-password-file my_playbook.yml
```

but I want to pass multiple password files, because I use multiple variables in the playbook that use different passwords that are stored in different password files.

How do I do that?

(I'm using Ansible 2.9.16, but can upgrade to 2.10.x if that helps, I'm not bound to any specific version)

Comment: Could you please mention your Ansible version?

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav I'm not bound any specific version. If there's a solution that works only with the latest version, I'll upgrade to that.

Comment: Okay, then check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the vault-ids concept(Introduced in Ansible v2.4) to fix your problem.
Sample command below,

`ansible-playbook --vault-id dev@dev-password --vault-id prod@prompt site.yml`

`dev` -> Is the vault ID

`dev-password` -> Points to the password to be used

`prod` -> Another vault ID

`prompt` -> Prompts for the password

Ansible Docs for complete workflow and setup: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/vault.html#vault-ids-and-multiple-vault-passwords

**Vault IDs setup with existing password files**

1. Ansible config file setup

`vault_identity_list = vaultid1@~/path_to_pass1_file/.pass1 , vaultid2@~/path_to_pass2_file/.pass2`

2. Encrypt the file using the respective vaultid

`ansible-vault encrypt --encrypt-vault-id vaultid1 file_to_be_encrypted_1`
`ansible-vault encrypt --encrypt-vault-id vaultid2 file_to_be_encrypted_2`

3. Run your playbook and it will automatically pick the configuration from the `ansible.cfg` and decrypt the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Question though: I don't have any vault IDs, just two password files that each contain a password. What do I supply as the vault IDs in that case?

Comment: @Alex, Updated my answer and added step by step process for your query.